# Observable inside Observable array that track two elements KO js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

[image: Site Screen Shot]

Array of 3 radio box and input text that are tied together, selection of radio would dynamically pop text that user can add on top of. I'm able to populate the text box, but can't track changes of both afterward as I need some sort of observable that trace both change and give me the total value of both (e.g. 'File: c:\temp\data.cs'

Here my HTML

```
  <!-- ko foreach: includes  -->

                <div class="col-md-3 mt-3 offset-3 ">
                    <input class="col-md-2 " type="radio" value="file:" data-bind="checked: type, attr: { name: name }">File
                    <input class="col-md-2" type="radio" value="dir:" data-bind="checked: type, attr: { name: name }">Dirs
                    <input class="col-md-2" type="radio" value="glob:" data-bind="checked: type, attr: { name: name }">Glob
                </div>

                <div class=" col-md-6 pt-3 ">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" required data-bind="attr: { name: name } , value: value">
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-3 mt-4 mb-4 offset-4" id="firstPath">
                <button type="button" class="form-control btn btn-info ml-3" data-bind="click: addInclude">Add new include line</button>
            </div>
```

And my JS

```
self.includes = ko.observableArray([{
        name: "package[][includes][0]",
        type: "file:",
        value: ko.observable()
    }]);


self.addInclude = function () {
 self.includes.push({
            name: `package[][includes][${includeCounter++}]`,
            type: `file`,
            value: ko.observable("file")
        });
    };
```

How to make the value property in includes observable array track both radio selection + input text value for the related row ?
I tried Ko.Computed but the issue is when initialing the type in includes observable is not define yet for relative row (default value for type is file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type member should be observable. So, through subscribe, you can set the value of value each time type changes.

```
function myViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  self.includeCounter = 0;

  self.includes = ko.observableArray([]);

  self.addInclude = function () {
    var type = ko.observable('file:');
    var value = ko.observable('file:');
    type.subscribe((newValue) => {
      value(newValue);
    }, self);

    var item = {
      name: `package[][includes][${self.includeCounter++}]`,
      type: type,
      value: value
    };
    self.includes.push(item);
  };

  self.addInclude();
}

var vm = new myViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```